# Is there a way to change a portion of the symbol's degree in phantasm?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

[image: Currently, this is what I have.]

I want to change the degree of each portion of the symbols to look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice script you can use, called "RotateTowardPoint".

You would place a path in the center (where you want them all rotated towards).

Then select all and run the script. (I ran it a few times for better results)

Check out [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/116219/63979) for the script and more info.

**Before**

[image: before]

**After**

[image: after]

You'll notice it doesn't do a perfect job, I assume that's a limitation of the computer trying to guess which way you want them all *pointing*.