# Illustrator: orient group of lines to point to the center of the group

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rotate

I have a group of lines that are all parallel to each other and are disposed in a circle:

[image: Starting disposition]

I would like to rotate all of them so that their axis points to the center of the circle. The center of each line, however, needs to stay where it is now. Something like this (I did it quickly by hand, so it's not perfect):
[image: After rotation]

Is there a quick way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corner pointing arrow grid](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116215/63979)

Answer (score 1):

You have got an answer that suggests you to draw the lines originally to the wanted orientations. That's easy if the lines are equal and should be placed along a circle.

But rotating them manually can be done perfectly. Have a target object which has an anchor point where you want the lines point to.

[image]

The X in the middle has got an inserted anchor at the crossing. The X is also locked to be sure it stays unmoved.

In the right the lines are selected one by one. The selected line is rotated with the rotate tool.

There's Smart Guides and Snap to point =ON in the View menu. The rotate tool snaps to the center node of the X.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Illustrator that could do that natively, however I suppose it could be scripted if you feel so inclined.

If you don't mind the lines being rotated all by the same amount equidistantly around a circle, then you could draw one line and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Rotate tool to move the rotation origin, set the angle, then use the Copy button, and then repeat each rotation using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

If you want lines spaced more randomly, then it would probably easier to start off with the vertical lines arranged in a horizontal row, then you could turn them into an art brush, and then apply the brush to a circle.

[image]

Note: in the brush above I also included a line with no stroke at the end of the brush to create a space between the first and last lines when applied to the circle.